# property values get corrupt

Tags: properties, wix, windows-installer, custom-action

I pass property values like this:

```
property1=value1;property2=value2
```

but sometimes values contain ';' symbols, which causes WiX to deserialize the property string incorrectly. I've tried enquoting values with double quotes

```
property1="value1";property2="value2"
```

but that didn't help. So how can I deal with this?

Comment: It seems to work fine for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replying [to request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5704753/property-values-get-corrupt/5705464#5705464) in comments. To double semi-colons in a property value, you can use JScript CA:

```
<CustomAction Id="DoubleSemiColons" Script="jscript">
    <![CDATA[

    var s = Session.Property("property2");
    var re = /;/g;
    var r = s.replace(re, ";;");

    Session.Property("property2") = r;

    ]]>
</CustomAction>
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I've tested it and it works! But why didn't you enquote the re variable value? I thought that it is a string value, but when I enquote it then it stops working.

Comment: @Bogdan0x400 `re` is not a string, it is a _regular expression pattern_, where `g` is _global_ flag to replace all occurrences of `;` in `s`, without it only the first occurrence would be doubled.

Answer (score 3):

I thought we just saw this question the other day ( short answer is escape it with ;; )

For a more detailed discussion,  if you want to understand how to use Type 51 custom actions to set properties to be deserialized by a DTF custom action,  write a little console app like this

```
var cad = new CustomActionData();
cad.Add("property1","myvalue");
cad.Add("property2","my;value");
Console.WriteLine(cad.ToString());
Console.Read();
```

The result will be:

> property1=myvalue;property2=my;;value

This should help you know how to format every scenario possible.    However, eventually you might findyourself in a situation where a Type 51 CA isn't enough.  In that case you'd write an immeadiate CA to build up your CustomActionData collection and then use the Session.DoAction method to schedule your deferred CA passing the CustomActionData through to it.

Comment: how do I escape a property before passing it to my custom action?

Comment: @Bogdan0x400 The example Christopher provided has the answer to your question: if the value of property contains `;`, then you have to have it doubled so that the property values contains `;;`.

Comment: @Alexey Ivanov for example the user inputs a connection string that contains lots of ;. How do you add the semicolons to that property, which is based on textbox input? Is there a built-in custom action for that? I can't add the semicolons in my custom action because when I try to modify the property then it deserializes incorrectly.

Comment: @Bogdan0x400 I don't think there's a standard CA to do it, see [a sample JScript action](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5704753/property-values-get-corrupt/5715805#5715805)